# How to return a string of arrays from another method?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

This is homework for a class I am taking. So I do not expect anyone to write code for me, just guidance for pseudo code is fantastic :)

So I have been given a main method by my teacher. This method creates an array of objects, sorts them into alphabetical order, then calls another method with "System.out.println(loans[0].Schedule());". This method should print out a schedule of that loan. What it is is kinda irrelevant, so I won't go into detail about it, but the method has a 2D array in it.

As you may know, the Schedule method cannot be void (I don't no why, it just gives me an error). So I tried making it "public String[][] Schedule()", but my teacher said that will not work since the way it is being called, "System.out.println(loans[0].Schedule());", println cannot handle printing a full 2D array.

Does anyone have any alternatives? All help is appreciated.

Comment: 1+ for not requesting *teh codez*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are calling it like you note above, `System.out.println(loans[0].schedule());`, then the `schedule()` method must return a String, not an array of String, not a 2-D array of String, but a single String since that is what println is expecting (either that or an object that has a decent `toString()` method override, but that's the subject of another discussion).

Note that the `schedule()` method should begin with a lower-case letter to comply with Java naming conventions.

Note also that the reason that `schedule()` cannot return void is because it has to return an object for the `println(...)` method to print.

For more details regarding this answer, you may want to give more details about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Very helpful answer! Thank you!

In my schedule method, I must actually generate a schedule, which can be lines and lines long, with calculations. Do you suggest I keep concatenating these to a single sting?

For example:

```
String schedule = ""
for(int i = 1; i <= term + 1; i++)
{
  schedule += i + ":";
  schedule += payment + "";
  //And so on so on for the rest of the schedule
}
```

Comment: I think it would be better if you edited your original question to ask these extra details rather than post it as an answer.

Comment: Yep, this is not an answer and shouldn't be posted as an answer. Instead edit your original post, add this to it, and notify anyone you want to notify via comments.

Comment: And also to answer these types of questions, you can't state `"What it is is kinda irrelevant, so I won't go into detail about it, but the method has a 2D array in it."` because this information is *very* relevant to figuring out the correct answer.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help. Will add that to my question now :)